# How to append special data to AWS SES email sending?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an app with two configurations - dev and prod. Both have own DynamoDB instances for data. I'm using SES to send notification emails.

Email can cause bounce or complaint if there are problems with recipient, so when I receive bounce/complaint I push it to special SNS topic, to which corresponding lambda is attached.

Lambda put bounce/complaint email to black list of emails that are excluded from future notification sending.

The problem is that I have the same lambda for dev/prod configurations and would like to have a way of determining which notification (dev or prod) caused problem and put email into corresponding black list - dev or prod.

I thought for such purpose tags for sendEmail() params can be used:

```
  Tags: [
    {
      Name: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      Value: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
    },
    /* more items */
  ]
```

Unfortunately they are not stored in incoming bounce/complaint event even with "Include original headers" option in SES SNS notification configuration settings.

Is there any way to solve the task?

Comment: The only way I see now is to change "from" email address. But I'm trying to solve the problem without any email appearance change for recipient.